# How to Migrate the OS installation to a new disk?

Tags: partitioning

My media PC / home server has a 1.8TB hard disk, partitioned as follows:

```
Device Boot Start End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1   *   2048        218361855   218359808   104.1G  83  Linux
/dev/sda2       3896788992  3907028991  10240000    4.9G    5   Extended
/dev/sda3       218361856   3896788991  3678427136  1.7T    83  Linux
/dev/sda5       3896791040  3907028991  10237952    4.9G    82  Linux swap / Sol
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Mount points (including backup disk sdf, not shown above) are as follows:

```
# df -h
Filesystem  Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
udev        3.4G    0       3.4G    0%      /dev
tmpfs       693M    19M     674M    3%      /run
/dev/sda1   103G    60G     38G     61%     /
tmpfs       3.4G    183M    3.3G    6%      /dev/shm
tmpfs       5.0M    4.0K    5.0M    1%      /run/lock
tmpfs       3.4G    0       3.4G    0%      /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdf1   462G    358G    82G     82%     /mnt/backup
/dev/sda3   1.7T    935G    705G    58%     /home
tmpfs       693M    48K     693M    1%      /run/user/1000
tmpfs       693M    0       693M    0%      /run/user/0
```

I'd like to do two things:

- Migrate the OS to a new 120GB SSD.
- Recover the space in /dev/sda1 to use in the main /home partition (currently /dev/sda3).

Couple of questions:

- Should I use gparted to set up the initial partitions and clonezilla to clone from old to new?
- Should I also clone /dev/sda2 (Extended) and /dev/sda5 (Swap)?
- Once cloned, will I be able to delete the original partitions which were cloned, and merge the empty space back into the main /dev/sda3 partition?

Comment: Remember that Ubuntu does *not* have a Product Key, one of the main reasons to migrate via cloning. One solution is to simply use  the normal Ubuntu installer and do a clean-install on the new hard drive, then copy your /home data across. There is generally no need to clone swap (new releases of Ubuntu often lack a swap partition entirely). Yes, you can use gparted to destroy/merge old partitions...but use with care lest you wipe precious data instead.

Comment: Thanks.  This option has not been discounted (especially with the new LTS due shortly), although there is a "hassle factor" in starting again from scratch.

Comment: In the end, cloning just caused a load of issues with duplicate UUIDs, bios and grub.  Formatted and reinstalled, mounting the old OS in /mnt/oldOS in order to retrieve settings and reapply them to the new install.